# Making thread-safe calls to windows forms controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The MSDN article: [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)
says we should use async delegate to make the call. But why does the async delegate make the call safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Windows controls use the Component Object Model (COM) single-threaded apartment (STA) model because those underlying controls are apartment-threaded. Furthermore, many of the controls use the message pump for many operations. This model says that all function calls to each control must be on the same thread that created the control. Invoke (and BeginInvoke and EndInvoke) marshals method calls to the proper thread.*

From Bill Wagner's  More Effective C#. Item 16. Understand Cross-Thread Calls in Windows Forms and WPF

Answer (score 1):

You'll call control.BeginInvoke() or control.Invoke() and that method will take care of inserting your delegate in the GUI dispatch thread safely, so a bit later on your delegate will be processed and executed in the GUI thread and not the thread you'r in

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is this: You shouldn't update the UI Controls from a thread other than the one on which the control was created (UI / Main Thread). Otherwise you may see some unpredictable behavior.

If you need to update the UI from a worker thread (other than the main thread) you need to switch back to the UI Thread before updating the UI.

The article suggests using

- `IsInvokeRequired` (which returns true if the current thread is not the one in which UI was created.) and `Invoke(delegate)` which runs the delegate on the correct/UI thread. This is useful when you want to update the UI **in between** the async process. e.g. update progress on the UI.
- `BackgroundWorker` which executes registered handlers to its `DoWork` event async. on a worker thread and runs the registered handlers to its `RunWorkerCompleted` event on the calling thread. This is ideal if you want to update the UI with something **after** the async task has completed. e.g. post a Done indication on the UI

Answer (score 0):

Because, windows forms controls are designed in that way, so they can be accessed only from within he thread, which owes them. And the async delegate, when used correctly, makes the call safe.

The actual answer to the given question is contained in the second paragraph of the given MSDN article =)

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other thread-related bugs are possible, such as race conditions and deadlocks. It is important to make sure that access to your controls is performed in a thread-safe way.

You should check whether you can access control immediately, without indirection ( checking the InvokeRequired property ), if you can't, you should access it asynchronously ( very simplified explanation: the system will wait until it can safely access a control )

Comment: And how could an async delegate avoid that?